# RightCurlyBraceDifferentLineAsNextBlockCheck reported though not active

Tags: java, sonarqube

the rule squid:RightCurlyBraceDifferentLineAsNextBlockCheck is not active for the profile we are using

At least this is what I conclude when searching the rule. If under `Quality Profile`, I select `active`, it says `No Coding Rules`. If I select `inactive`, I do see the rule in the overview.

Clicking on the rule then shows this

[image]

So it has the button to active the rule, but nevertheless reports sonarqube 2222 violations for this rule, although it is not part of any ruleset. When clicking on them I do see the locations of the violations.

How can it be that although it seems to be inactive, it gets reported ?
And what do I need to do to completely silent this rule.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactivating a rule from a profile does not automatically close all issues created by that rule. For that to happen, an *analysis* is required on each of the relevant projects. *Then* old issues will be closed.